# Advertising for google+ followers

Tags: advertising, google-plus

Is there a way to advertise with google to specifically increase the number of followers to my google+ page? I got it to work pretty well with facebook and now I'm trying to increase the visibility of my google+ page.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of content does your website have?  I would start here, https://support.google.com/business/answer/4569148?hl=en&ref_topic=6000821, specifically the pages on Link your Google+ page and your website and Add the Google+ badge to your website.  If your website contains pages where an "author" has written it, you can also link those pages to a Google+ profile:  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2539557?hl=en&ref_topic=6003069

Comment: I don't want people to go on the website, I just want them to see my google+ page since it offers different type of content. Your link has a section about "social extensions" I'll read that up, might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Those require an AdWords campaign, which cost money on a pay per click basis.